# C cross compiling: sprintf only writes "\0" character after array of size [512][4] number [111][1] is initialized to 0

Tags: c, printf, uart, nxp-microcontroller

This is a nutcracker. 
Cross compiling for NXP imx.6 on ubuntu 16.04
Using gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_2-2015q4 for compiling. 
Debugging using jlink base. Code compiles and runs without errors but the output is wrong.

### The code:

file:uart_print.c

```
#include "imx_uart.h"
uart_instance = HW_UART4; # defined in another file

void uartWriteString(void *str) {

     uint8_t mystr;                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
     while (*(uint8_t *)(str) != '\0')     {                                                                                    
        mystr = *(uint8_t *)str++;                                                                                             
        uart_putchar(uart_instance, &mystr);   //Write data                                                                    
     }                                                                                                                          
}
```

file: myfile.c

```
#include "uart_print.h"
#include "sdk.h"
void myfunc() {
    char str[40];
    int i, char_written;
    int myarray[512][4];
    char_written = sprintf(str, "123456789"); //This works str="123456789\0"
    //DEBUGGER output here: char_written = 9
    for (i = 0; i < 512; i++){
        myarray[i][0] = 0;
        myarray[i][1] = 0;  // <-- Problem starts here
        myarray[i][2] = 0;
        myarray[i][3] = 0;
    }
    char_written = sprintf(str, "0123456789"); 
    uartWriteString(str); //uart: str=\023456789\0
    //DEBUGGER output here: char_written = 0
```

Something is happening in that for-loop which disturbs the sprintf function.
I therefore tried to use sprintf in the for-loop:

```
    ...
    myarray[i][0] = 0;
    char_written = sprintf(str, "0123456789");
    myarray[i][1] = 0;
    char_written = sprintf(str, "0123456789");
    myarray[i][2] = 0;
    myarray[i][3] = 0;
}
```

### DEBUGGER output:

`str = 123456789 if myarray[0 - 110][0-3] = 0 and myarray[111][0] = 0`

`str = \023456789 if myarray[111][1] = 0` and always after this;
`sprintf` will never work correctly after `myarray[111][1] = 0` has been set

If I remove `myarray[111][1] = 0`
`myarray[111][2] = 0` will make the `sprintf write str=1234\06789`, here only the first 4 symbols are written.

I cannot figure out the connection, is there some issue with memory? Are they overwriting some important registers. Given that I have spent two days on this now any input is very welcome?

Comment: Local variables are usually put on the stack. How much stack is allocated for your program?

Comment: Why are you showing us `uartWriteString` when you don't call it anywhere?  Is it part of the problem?

Comment: `uart_putchar(uart_instance, &mystr);` Are you sure, the function expects a pointer instead of a single character?

Comment: Simple debugging: Incrementally remove code until the problem goes away.

Comment: `mystr = *(uint8_t *)str++;` is an error. You can not increment a `void *`. If you don't see an error message then consider changing compiler flags to get conforming mode.

Comment: You probably have a stack overflow. Look through the platform documentation, linker script etc. to figure out what the stack size is and where it is

Comment: "compiles OK but ... run wrong" welcome to C world.

Comment: You could try changing `int myarray[512][4]` to `static int myarray[512][4]`, or moving its declaration outside of the function.

Comment: @SteveSummit, you are correct, I actually used it for putting characters from str to print them. I skipped it here, because the debugger also provides the same information.

Comment: Is this the correct signature  `UART_Putchar(UART_Type* base, uint8_t data)`?  Review `uint8_t mystr; ... uart_putchar(uart_instance, &mystr);`

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes that worked! What is going on here?

Comment: @MattisAsp Stack overflow.  Strange things can happen when you have large, local, stack-allocated variables.  Either the stack isn't big enough, or it has trouble growing fast enough to accommodate them.  How big is "big"?  There's no clear boundary, but 4k is clearly "big".  Putting `static` in front of it means it's no longer allocated on the stack, so the problem goes away. Sometimes you can get your compiler to warn you if your functions have local variable allocations that are too big for your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Several things to consider here:

1) You can initialize your matrix easier/faster using memset:

```
memset(myarray, 0, sizeof(myarray[0][0]) * m * n);
```

2) The max lenght of the assigned string can be better controlled using snprintf instead of sprintf.

3) Where is "charwrt" defined?

4) What are you trying to do after the for loop? You are overriding "str" again and again:

```
char_written= sprintf(str, "0123456789"); //str=\023456789\0
...
myarray[i][0] = 0;
char_written= sprintf(str, "0123456789");
myarray[i][1] = 0;
char_written= sprintf(str, "0123456789");
```

5) After iterating the loop for, "i" value is always 512

6) Probably if you post a simpler but working/compiling code reproducing your problem we can help even more.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: 1) memset does not solve this issue. The same issue stil exists. Also the problem exist across different filetypes such as float. I cannot reliably use memset on float. 
2) Ok, I can try that
3) chrwrt is now changed to char_written, sorry for that detail. 
4) In the for loop: I am debugging every step to see which loop iteration the sprintf fails. I am overwriting because it is failing after the i has reached 111, and we write to myarray[111][1].

Comment: Probably you provide uartWriteString for some reason, but that function is not called in your snippet. Function "myfunc" as is compiles fine under x86_64 with gcc. Valgrind says all it's ok. It would be helpful to provide not just an snippet but the exact source code of the function that is failing (myfunc).

Comment: I am not shure how to provide you with all that, what exactly from my source code do you want? It's pretty big given that it's based on the imx-sdk.